# razor, jquery: when checkbox is checked uncheck some other checkboxes, but it unchecks ALL checkboxes on that page

Tags: jquery, razor

I have a few checkboxes on my page. One is rendered statically, while the others are rendered from the model:

```
 <table>
     <tr>
         <td>
             @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.AllLangsChecked, new { onchange = "checkedChanged" })
             <script>
                 $('input:checkbox').change(function () {
                     $('input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', false);
                 })
             </script>
             <label>Alle Sprachen</label>
         </td>
     </tr>
     @for (int i = 0; i < Model.checkLangs.Count; i++)
     {
         <tr>
             <td>
                 @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.checkLangs[i].Name)
                 @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.checkLangs[i].LanguageId)
                 @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.checkLangs[i].isChecked)
                 <label>@Model.checkLangs[i].Name</label>
             </td>
         </tr>
     }
 </table>
```

Now you can see my  tag. Its job is basically to uncheck all of the dynamic checkboxes when the top one is checked.

This does work fine.
However, the script also unchecks litereally ALL checkboxes on that page. (there are a few more).

But I only want those from the loop to be disabled.

How would you go on about this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not good about that razor syntax I guess 
But I have some thoughts about jquery problem 
You jquery selector works for all `input:checkbox` on the page
So you should add some more selectors for checkboxes that you need
Try to add class to your `table` tag 
and add that class to your jquery checkbox selector query
something like that

```
<table class="some-class">
     <tr>
         <td>
             @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.AllLangsChecked, new { onchange = "checkedChanged" })
             <script>
                 $('.some-class input:checkbox').change(function () {
                     $('.some-class input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', false);
                 })
             </script>
             <label>Alle Sprachen</label>
         </td>
     </tr>
     @for (int i = 0; i < Model.checkLangs.Count; i++)
     {
         <tr>
             <td>
                 @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.checkLangs[i].Name)
                 @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.checkLangs[i].LanguageId)
                 @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.checkLangs[i].isChecked)
                 <label>@Model.checkLangs[i].Name</label>
             </td>
         </tr>
     }
 </table>
```

this jquery selector works only for checkbox inside the table

Comment: this was the way to do it! i tried giving the checkboxes an ID but that only worked on the first of them all ( i guess bc otherwise I have a double Id) but your solution to wrap stuff inside a class worked perfectly" thank you!